# state being forgotten on componentDidMount react

Tags: reactjs

I'm having an issue where I have a method called userLogin, where a user makes a post request to my server, and if they correctly login with user/pass, they have access to the boards data on the server. I also set a state called isloggedin so react keeps track of the state of whether the user is logged in.

On logging it it works, isloggedin is set to true, they have access to the boards, however the page doesn't reload and show the boards, even though it is successfully GET requesting the data. On reloading the page, the boards show, however isloggedin is then set to false. Not sure why it's not rerendering "/" because the state of isloggedin has changed, and I thought react rerenders on state change. Any help would be appreciate, cheers.

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './homePage/home';
import Board from './boardPage/board';
import Signup from './signupPage/signup';
import Login from './loginPage/login';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      boards: {},
      loggedin: false
    }
    this.addBoard = this.addBoard.bind(this)
    this.addList = this.addList.bind(this)
    this.addCard = this.addCard.bind(this)
    this.userSignup = this.userSignup.bind(this)
    this.userLogin = this.userLogin.bind(this)
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this)
    this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/boards').then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        boards: res.data
      })
    })
  }

  addBoard(board) {
    axios.post('/boards', board).then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        boards: res.data
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Not logged in")
    })
  }

  addList(boardId, list) {
    axios.post('/boards/' + boardId + '/lists', list).then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        boards: res.data
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  addCard(boardId, listId, Card) {
    axios.post('/boards/' + boardId + '/lists/' + listId + '/cards', Card).then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        boards: res.data
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  userSignup(userAndPass) {
    axios.post('/signup', userAndPass).then().catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  userLogin(userAndPass) {
    axios.post('/login', userAndPass).then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        boards: res.data,
        loggedin: true
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  handleDelete(e, id) {
    this.setState({boards: delete this.state.boards.id})
  }

  handleLogout() {
    this.setState({loggedin: false})
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={(props) => <Home {...props} boards={this.state.boards} addBoard={this.addBoard} loggedin={this.state.loggedin} handleLogout={this.handleLogout}/>}/>
          <Route path="/boards/:boardId" component={(props) => <Board {...props} boards={this.state.boards} addList={this.addList} addCard={this.addCard} userSignup={this.userSignup}/>}/>
          <Route path="/signup" component={(props) => <Signup {...props} userSignup={this.userSignup}/>}/>
          <Route path="/login" component={(props) => (
            this.state.loggedin
            ? <Redirect to="/"/> 
            : <Login {...props} userLogin={this.userLogin}/>
          )}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think, you need to bind `userLogin(userAndPass) {.` use `userLogin = (userAndPass) => {`

Comment: Where are you defining your initial state?

Comment: I took out some of the code just to focus on where I thought the problem might be. Do you want me to include the full page?

Comment: I added the full page of code. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Can you console.log(res.data) and tell us what you get?

Comment: Object {boards: "", loggedin: true}
boards
:
""
loggedin
:
true
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Then when i refresh, it correctly loads the default state I want for when the user logs in.



Object {boards: Object, loggedin: false}
boards
:
Object
tutorialBoard
:
Object
important
:
true
lists
:
Object
name
:
"Tutorial Board (Start Here!)"
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
loggedin
:
false
__proto__
:
Object